# Facebook oAuth in Android "Failed to read calling package's signature"

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I have encountered this problem when I am using,

05-22 02:14:56.840: E/Facebook-ProxyAuth(966): Failed to read calling package's signature.

And it did not call onActivityResult.

```
       if(!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
       facebook.authorize(this, new String[] {"publish_stream", "offline_access"}, new DialogListener() {
           @Override
           public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
               Log.d(TAG, "onComplete");    
           }

           @Override
           public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
               Log.e(TAG, "onFacebookError" + error.toString());
           }

           @Override
           public void onError(DialogError e) {
               Log.e(TAG, "onError" + e.toString());

           }

           @Override
           public void onCancel() {
               Log.d(TAG, "onCancel");                 
           }
       });
   }



@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult");
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Actually, I am successfully call this function before. I don't know why starting from when, it is failed. And I found this issue, I already re-generate the key and update my facebook app. The problems is the same.

On the other hand, I re-create a simple and new project, using the same code. It can successfully login. I wonder what kind of setting I did.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In my case I was trying to add Twitter too and to do it I changed the manifest. The problem was this line in the manifes, in the activity that calls that method:

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

I took it out and it worked again.